# How can I remove HBASE table in transition

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, cloudera-cdh

HBASE version 2.1.0-cdh6.3.2

2 master servers

ACTIVE MASTER

STANDBY MASTER

I have a table with 48 regions all in transition.

Table is showing as ENABLED.

1 region is CLOSED

47 regions are OPENING

Unable to DISABLE table.

Customer is content if the table has to be deleted - it is only 6K on HDFS.

```
 PID Name State Submitted Last_Update Parameters
 18949 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.DeleteTableProcedure RUNNABLE 2020-11-04 12:04:04 UTC 2020-11-04 12:04:04 UTC [{}, {"userInfo"=>{"effectiveUser"=>"root"}, "tableName"=>{"namespace"=>"YWxmYQ==", "qualifier"=>"cmZpbGVuYW1lZXh0"}}]
 18950 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.DeleteTableProcedure RUNNABLE 2020-11-04 12:08:58 UTC 2020-11-04 12:08:58 UTC [{}, {"userInfo"=>{"effectiveUser"=>"root"}, "tableName"=>{"namespace"=>"YWxmYQ==", "qualifier"=>"cmZpbGVuYW1lZXh0"}}]
 18951 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.DisableTableProcedure RUNNABLE 2020-11-04 12:44:33 UTC 2020-11-04 12:44:33 UTC [{}, {"userInfo"=>{"effectiveUser"=>"root"}, "tableName"=>{"namespace"=>"YWxmYQ==", "qualifier"=>"cmZpbGVuYW1lZXh0"}, "skipTableStateCheck"=>false}]
 18259 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.DisableTableProcedure WAITING 2020-11-03 07:24:17 UTC 2020-11-03 07:24:17 UTC [{"state"=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 7]}, {"userInfo"=>{"effectiveUser"=>"root"}, "tableName"=>{"namespace"=>"YWxmYQ==", "qualifier"=>"cmZpbGVuYW1lZXh0"}, "skipTableStateCheck"=>false}]
 18260 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.assignment.UnassignProcedure SUCCESS 2020-11-03 07:24:17 UTC 2020-11-03 07:24:18 UTC [{"transitionState"=>"REGION_TRANSITION_FINISH", "regionInfo"=>{"regionId"=>"1557760164826", "tableName"=>{"namespace"=>"YWxmYQ==", "qualifier"=>"cmZpbGVuYW1lZXh0"}, "startKey"=>"", "endKey"=>"MA==", "offline"=>false, "split"=>false, "replicaId"=>0}, "hostingServer"=>{"hostName"=>"ba-wtmp04.hq.com", "port"=>16020, "startCode"=>"1601061167123"}}]
 18261 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.assignment.UnassignProcedure WAITING_TIMEOUT 2020-11-03 07:24:17 UTC 2020-11-24 09:52:22 UTC [{"transitionState"=>"REGION_TRANSITION_DISPATCH", "regionInfo"=>{"regionId"=>"1557760164826", "tableName"=>{"namespace"=>"YWxmYQ==", "qualifier"=>"cmZpbGVuYW1lZXh0"}, "startKey"=>"MA==", "endKey"=>"MQ==", "offline"=>false, "split"=>false, "replicaId"=>0}, "hostingServer"=>{"hostName"=>"ba-wtmp07.hq.com", "port"=>16020, "startCode"=>"1600936054386"}, "attempt"=>3048}]
...
etc
```

I tried searching for information regarding removing/killing the procedures relating to this table but, although I found a reference to 'abort_procedure' that command/function doesn't seem to exist.

A previous attempt to disable the table - as well as removing the znodes - is still running as you can see at the top of the output. So after restarting the master, the transition procedures appeared to restart.

I was hoping to find a hbase 'kill' equivalent that would allow me to halt the existing procedures and then attempt to disable/drop the table, or delete it entirely via zkshell.

The table is empty but the transitions are preventing balancing from operating properly.

Any information would be a great help at this time.

Because there are disable/delete procedures here, no further hbck can run to fixholes, etc.

HBase service was restarted Nov 5 and, as you can see, previous procedures were still available/running.

Maybe there is a way to stop hbase, remove the procedures via some java process and then restart hbase with a clean procedure sheet?

There are NO region-in-transition children under /hbase/.

Comment: Update: I shutdown hbase, removed hdfs data, removed zk node info, removed masterprocwals (backed up) and restarted hbase.

The tables do not exist in hbase. No files/dirs created after started for this table.  No locked procedures for this table.

However, the region in transition errors still exist.

I am at a loss here.  Somewhere, some reference to these tasks lingers.

Comment: I had to do a build of hbase-operator-tools and run that against hbase:meta with extraRegionsInMeta.